# str_replace only a certain part of printed string?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have ran into a problem. 
I want to replace only the part in parenthesis, but the problem is if the value in parenthesis is 1 or something else in the same part ([x(xxx:x:x)xx];), it will end up replacing that also, which I need the x(value) at the end of each part.

```
[0(267:0:0)x1];[1(257:0:0)x1];[2(256:0:0)x1];[3(258:0:0)x1];[4(261:0:0)x1];   [5(262:0:0)x64];[6(320:0:0)x10];[7(17:0:0)x32];[8(295:0:0)x2];[9(35:0:0)x2];[10(44:1:1)x6];[11(0:0:0)x1];[12(0:0:0)x1];[13(0:0:0)x1];[14(0:0:0)x1];[15(0:0:0)x1];[16(0:0:0)x1];[17(0:0:0)x1];[18(0:0:0)x1];[19(0:0:0)x1];[20(0:0:0)x1];[21(0:0:0)x1];[22(0:0:0)x1];[23(0:0:0)x1];[24(0:0:0)x1];[25(0:0:0)x1];[26(0:0:0)x1];[27(0:0:0)x1];[28(0:0:0)x1];[29(0:0:0)x1];[30(0:0:0)x1];[31(0:0:0)x1];[32(0:0:0)x1];[33(0:0:0)x1];[34(0:0:0)x1];[35(0:0:0)x1];[103(0:0:0)x1];[102(0:0:0)x1];[101(0:0:0)x1];[100(0:0:0)x1];
```

I cannot get this working. If I try to replace a 1 value in the part in parenthesis, it ends up changing all of the 1's on the printed part.

Also keep in mind that the zero's in the parenthesis won't always be 0's.

Here's what I tried:

```
$items = $row['inventory'];
$test = str_replace('267', '<img href="../assets/images/items/iron_sword.png">', $items);
echo $items;
```

I only tried one line of code to see how it would work.

I'm trying to replace the part in parenthesis with an image (for example, the first one is [0(267:0:0)x1];. I want to replace (267:0:0) with an image...

Comment: your explanation is bad. Give exactly what you want?

Comment: Show the code you tried

Comment: You want to replace only (267:0:0) with a image or there are more items to replace ?

Comment: I want to be able to have a universal code that will replace only the things in those parenthesis. If you look above, there's a whole list of them. If you're wondering what they are, they're minecraft inventory items.

Comment: you should tokenize your string and work on individual tokens i think it can easily be tokenized using `;`

Comment: The problem with that is this list isn't permanent. Like I said, it's a minecraft player's inventory. It updates every minute, so all of these values will change to what the player has.

Comment: why don't you use `str_replace('(267:', '(<img....>:', $items);`

Comment: PERFECT. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace all (***:*:*) pattern with the same image, you cant try preg_replace:

```
$str = "[0(267:0:0)x1];[1(257:0:0)x1];[2(256:0:0)x1];[3(258:0:0)x1];[4(261:0:0)x1];";
$res = preg_replace("/\(\d+\:\d+\:\d+\)/",'<img href="../assets/images/items/iron_sword.png">', $str);
```

You can see the result here: http://codepad.org/UIjGKv6n

If you want to replace different item with different image, then you need an translate map like this:

```
$from = array(
    '(267:0:0)',
    '(257:0:0)',
    ...
);
$to = array(
    '<img href="../assets/images/items/iron_sword.png">',
    '<img href="../assets/images/items/other.png">',
    ...
);
$res = str_replace($from, $to, $str);
```

And if you have other requirements, you can just modify the code as you need.